# Restructure text file details in the required output format using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am working on a text file to fix it into the required o/p format using Python.

Input file:

```
[ADD BD]
'text1'

[ADD BD]
'text2' 

[ADD BD]
'text3' 

[ADD TLD]
'text4'

[ADD BRD]
'text5'

[ADD BRD]
'text6'
```

I want all the text details under a single title string [ADD xxx]

Required output format:

```
[ADD BD]
'text1'
'text2'
'text3'

[ADD TLD]
'text4'

[ADD BRD]
'text5'
'text6'
```

I believe this can be done using regex. I am trying this but unable to fix the empty entries created in the list. Also, unable to figure out the way I can add the title string. Here is my progress:

```
test0 = """
[ADD BD]
'text1'

[ADD BD]
'text2' 

[ADD BD]
'text3' 

[ADD TLD]
'text4'

[ADD BRD]
'text5'

[ADD BRD]
'text6
"""
#test1 = re.sub("\[ADD BD\]", "", test0)
#print(test1)

#print the lines below the line [ADD BD]
test2 = re.sub("\[ADD TLD\]", "", test0)
print(test2)
# list of test2 with name list_ADD_BD
list_ADD_BD = test2.split("\n")
print(list_ADD_BD)

#remove empty lines from list_ADD_BD
list_ADD_BD = [x for x in list_ADD_BD if x]
print(list_ADD_BD)
```

How can I obtain the required o/p?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If test0 is having your string then you can achieve it by using defaultdict as it handles multiple values in list.

```
    from collections import defaultdict
    Res=""
    test_lst=test0.split("\n")
    print(test_lst)
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for i in range(0,len(test_lst)):
        if "[" in test_lst[i]:
            d[test_lst[i]].append(test_lst[i+1])
            
    for key,value in d.items():
        Res=Res+key+"\n"+str('\n'.join([str(elem) for elem in value]))+"\n"

    with open("myfile.txt","w") as f:
            f.write(Res)
```

Output:

```
[ADD BD]
'text1'
'text2' 
'text3' 

[ADD TLD]
'text4'

[ADD BRD]
'text5'
'text6
```

Comment: Appreciate your response! This does work, however, I want the output in the text file and in the required output format. Is there a way that you are aware of that can yield me this output in text file.

Comment: @Y.Pat edited answer to get output in your required format and write it into file

Comment: The line:  f.write(key+"\n"+str('\n'.join([str(elem) for elem in value]))+"\n"), outputs only the last tag and its text, hence the .txt file stores only the last tag! Any workaround to this, to include all required information in the output file?       PS: the terminal does print the required output, however can you please check the output file.

Comment: Please check edited answer now

Comment: I did an alternate fix for this: ```with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    for key,value in d.items():
        f.write(key+"\n"+str('\n'.join([str(elem) for elem in value]))+"\n") ```                 
 GG!

Answer (score 0):

If all your tags start with `[` and all texts with `'`, then it's simply checking the first character, and storing result in directory, to group by tag.

```py
data = {}
curr_tag = ''
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.startswith('['):
            curr_tag = line.strip()
            continue
        if line.startswith('\''):
            if curr_tag not in data:
                data[curr_tag] = []
            data[curr_tag].append(line.strip())

for key in data:
    print(key)
    for text in data[key]:
        print(text)
```

Comment: Yes, the starting character is exactly as you mentioned. Thank you!

Comment: I did try the code and its throwing this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'startwith'. Did you get this error?

Comment: It should be `startswith()` not `startwith()`, my bad